# How to overlay text with a graphics and specify the relative position?

Tags: overlay

I have some random graphics with specified `ImageSize` and `AspectRatio`, e.g., this line

> g1 = Graphics[Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}}], 
>     ImageSize -> 230, AspectRatio -> 1/2]

and some text

> g2 = Text[Style["1+1", Red, Large, Bold], Background -> LightRed]

as shown below:

[image]

How do I "overlay" the text `g2` ontop of `g1` and specify the relative position? For example, I want the center of `g2` to be located at `{1/3,7/8}` of `g1`, which means 1/3 the width and 7/8 of the height of `g1`, both measured from the lower left corner of `g1`. By doing this, the text `g2` will be just below the first peak of `g1`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put text directly into `Graphics`thus

```
   Graphics[{Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}}], ImageSize -> 230, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2,
  Text[Style["1+1", Red, Large, Bold], {1/3 4, 7/8 1}, 
   Background -> LightRed]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have added `Frame-> True` so I could see the coordinates of where to put the text. Look up `Text` there is also an option for an offset.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you @Hugh for the answer. Is it possible to fill the space above the `line` with a solid color up to the upper frame?

Comment: All depends what you are trying to do. If you use `Plot` and express your line as a function then there are fill commands. However, if you are looking for geometric shapes then `Polygon` may be what you need.I can't be sure what your general case is until you show more details. This may be suitable for another question.